# Perform calculation on values in a string "3+4"

Tags: c#

What is the best way to do calculations on values in a string, for example:
"(3.25 * 4) / 1.25 + 10"

Comment: This has been featured on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384811/code-golf-mathematical-expression-evaluator-full-pemdas (I originally voted to close as a dupe of a different question, which was the wrong one and I can't change it now)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write math formula parser. 
If you don't want to write your own, check out this one

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MathParserLibrary.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen http://ncalc.codeplex.com ?

It's extensible, fast (e.g. has its own cache) enables you to provide custom functions and varaibles at run time by handling EvaluateFunction/EvaluateParameter events. Example expressions it can parse:

```
Expression e = new Expression("Round(Pow(Pi, 2) + Pow([Pi2], 2) + X, 2)");

  e.Parameters["Pi2"] = new Expression("Pi * Pi");
  e.Parameters["X"] = 10;

  e.EvaluateParameter += delegate(string name, ParameterArgs args)
    {
      if (name == "Pi")
      args.Result = 3.14;
    };

  Debug.Assert(117.07 == e.Evaluate());
```

It also handles unicode & many data type natively. It comes with an antler file if you want to change the grammer. There is also a fork which supports MEF to load new functions.

It also supports logical operators, date/time's strings and if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Converting from infix to postfix notation is one way of solving this problem, as you can use a stack to parse and compute the expression.

There are a dozen solutions available online.  Here's [one of them](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/patricklundin/MathExpParser12062005062213AM/MathExpParser.aspx).