# Perform a task written as a string

Tags: c#

I would like to execute a task written by the user. The app shows a textfield, the user enters, for example:

`"(3*10 + 900)/10"`

and the app shows `"93"` on the screen.

Is that possible through some simple way? If negative, is there any library for such thing?

Comment: You want expression calculator or more generic CS scripting (either already discussed) or something else?

Comment: How about "1 gram mass defect in megatons of TNT", "Prove n x (n^2 + 5) is evenly divisible by 6 for all positive integers." or "Wash my car."?  Hand it over the wall (or Internet) to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+gram+mass+defect+in+megatons+of+TNT).

Comment: Keep in mind though that the suggested libraries are not "eval(...) for c#"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perform calculation on values in a string "3+4"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386458/perform-calculation-on-values-in-a-string-34)

Answer (score 5):

You would like to use expression evaluator like [Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator](http://flee.codeplex.com/).

Or you can use DataTable's Compute method and write simple math expressions like this:

```
var result = new DataTable().Compute("(3*10+900)/10", null);
```

Comment: If this post answered your question, please select it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a math library with parsing capabilities. Someone posted a question about math .Net libraries over [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387430/recommended-math-library-for-c-net) [MathdotNet](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) looks like your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

We are using An [Eval Function for C# using JScript.NET (JavaScript](http://odetocode.com/code/80.aspx)) created  by [Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/default.aspx)