# Find answer to string equation without using eval()

Tags: php, regex, eval

I need a way of taking an equation given as a string and finding it's mathematical answer, the big caveat is that I can't use eval().

I know the equation will only ever contain numbers, the four mathematical operators (i.e. * / + -) and parentheses, it may or may not have spaces in the string. Here's a couple of examples.

```
4 * 4
4+6/3
(3 / 2)*(4+8)
(4+8) * 2
```

I'm guessing that it's going to have to be done with some kind of regex?

Comment: Evaluating string formulas is rather easy when they are as simple as this. See half a dozen answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384811/code-golf-mathematical-expression-evaluator-full-pemdas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Math expressions aren't regular. They're [context-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language).

Your best bet is to parse them using well-known math parsing algorithms like [the shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm). All you have to worry about is implementing the algorithm in PHP. You might even be able to find PHP implementations of it online.

Comment: It's amazing how much one can learn from just reading the answers on questions! This is new to me, cool! +1

Comment: This will give you a head start: `$tokens = token_get_all('<?php ' . $expression)`

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anybody's interested here is the algorithm I came up with in PHP for producing Reverse Polish Notation

```
function convertToRPN($equation)

{
    $equation = str_replace(' ', '', $equation);
    $tokens = token_get_all('<?php ' . $equation);
    $operators = array('*' => 1, '/' => 1, '+' => 2, '-' => 2);
    $rpn = '';
    $stack = array();
    $size = count($tokens);                                                 
    for($i = 1; $i < $size; $i++) {
        if(is_array($tokens[$i])) {
            $rpn .= $tokens[$i][1] . ' ';
        } else {
            if(empty($stack) || $tokens[$i] == '(') {
                $stack[] = $tokens[$i];
            } else {
                if($tokens[$i] == ')') {
                    while(end($stack) != '(') {
                        $rpn .= array_pop($stack);
                    }
                    array_pop($stack);
                } else {
                    while(!empty($stack) && end($stack) != '(' && $operators[$tokens[$i]] >= $operators[end($stack)]) {
                        $rpn .= array_pop($stack);
                    }
                    $stack[] = $tokens[$i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    while(!empty($stack)) {
        $rpn .= array_pop($stack);
    }

    return $rpn;
}
```